# Jquery scripts run only sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so basically, I've got a couple of Jquery scripts in the header which are designed to make a certain CSS class fade in and another scroll down. In CSS I have them both set to display: none since Jquery then goes on to do its thing and make them appear. The code I have is this:

```
<script src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.textbox').slideDown(2500);
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.logo').fadeIn(2500); });
</script>
```

Now that's been working fine ever since I made it, but I was just making some changes to my site and the scripts don't seem to run often. The only thing I've changed is the menu bar so I don't think that caused it. Anyway, so I tried messing with bits of my code to see why the content of my page wasn't showing, then I came to the conclusion that the Jquery script wasn't working as I removed display: none and it started working again.

```
.textbox {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.88);
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

So does anyone know why the Jquery script won't show my content? Would it be better to load JQuery from Google servers rather than from my own host?

JUST A QUICK EDIT: I think I have solved the problem. For some reason, the CSS was loading after the Jquery scripts had run (I think) so I changed the top line of the Jquery scripts to:

> $(window).load(function() {

which seems to have solved the problem (for now). Just felt I'd leave this note in case anyone else ever has the same problem.

Comment: A fiddle might help understand the situation better. And answering this question: "Would it be better to load JQuery from Google servers rather than from my own host?" - It would not make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Your scripts are fine, I would guess that some change to your site have broken some part of your html so it's not valid anymore. That can break javascript execution on the DOM. See the source html and try to find errors, you can also use online validators for that if needed - http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I've done some more fiddling with it and I've found that it always loads if I delete the cache before I load the page. I've not slept in ages so I'm a little lost sadly :(

Comment: Also, the validator shows no errors, other than some I had ages ago that I never changed due to compatibility issues.

Comment: Fiddle will help to understand the issue

Comment: Well,  your solution is a bit unconventional,  but if you think this solved your problem,  you can post it as an answer and the mark it as accepted.  It is better than updating your question with solution while having no answers(people tend to move on if they see no answers).

Comment: Post your fix as answer or else others will keep on investigating your issue since they see no answers in this post

Comment: I'm new here and don't have enough rep to answer until 8 hours after posting, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, like Fr0zenFyr said, this is an unconventional method, but, whatever was happening, my CSS seemed to load after the Jquery scripts had run, and therefore display:none was coming into play AFTER the Jquery scripts, therefore keeping the content hidden. I have fixed this by using

> $(window).load(function() {

Instead of document ready.

For some reason, the glitch was only affecting four of my pages so I only changed the code on them. I think it may have been a problem with my host, either way, if anyone else has the same problem, this may help.